# EventBus confusion

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm trying to send a list of objects from `ActivityTwo` to `MainActivity`

I have followed EventBus's [get started page](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) and called `register()` and `unregister()` methods from onStart and onStop, then i used `EventBus.getDefault().post()` to send the data.

On `MainActivity` I do not get anything unless I remove the `unregister()` call from `onStop()`.

My question is, am I using it correctly? should I be calling `unregister()` in `onDestroy()`? if so, why are they calling it from `onStop` if it will not pick up anything if the activity is stopped

**MainActivity**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(YoutubeData event) {

    System.out.print(event);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

**ActivityTwo**

```
private void sendYoutubeData() {
        if(youtubeData != null){

          EventBus.getDefault().post(youtubeData);
          finish();
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive the event in MainActivity when it's not visible, yes, you should place your `register()` and `unregister()` respectively in `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`.

If there's no listeners for your event, it will never be received, EXCEPT if it's a sticky event, in which case you will be able to receive it when registering. More information about Sticky Events [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/)

Comment: This answers the question but is not the best use case for these simple tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have to post the list with the post line of event bus and then you have to override onEvent() in your class.
[here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is a link which will be helpful.

what you have to do is define additional events like

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

now from the part where you get the data you post it to the event.

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Inside you activity you place a subscriber function which will be triggered when data is posted to event bus.
and there you use the posted data

```
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Use the data*/};
```

Answer (score 2):

You will not get any event since you are in activity two, which means your first activity is in a "stopped" state. Depending on what you want to achieve, you can try `startActivityForResult` or create a sticky event, but I wouldn't recommend using event bus for simple operations like this since it can lead to nasty hard to debug errors.

So I recommend you go with option 1, use `startActivityForResult`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to receive events on your Activity when your activity has no focus then you are probably doing something wrong. I would suggest moving the subscriber stuff to a static singleton class and from that class start the Activity with an Intent and some parameters when you have to manage some situation.